# Spreadsheet Update from external excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel-2016

I have been working on this code for sometime, taking what I can from other posts and learning as I go.  I am new to VBA.  I am trying to have a master spreadsheet update from other excel sheets.  I have wrote a code to check the value of column C and if it has a value in the Master that is not in the other to highlight the row red.  IF the other sheet has a value that the master does not it, inserts the entire row and highlights green.  The part that I can not seem to get working is how to update the existing rows with new information when the value of column C is a match.  Everytime I try, it messes everything up.

Here is my code:

```
    Sub FindDifferences()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim cel1 As Range
    Dim cel2 As Range
    Dim wkb1 As Workbook
    Dim wkb2 As Workbook
    Dim wks1 As Worksheet
    Dim wks2 As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long
    Dim r1 As Range
    Dim r2 As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim lastRow1 As Integer
    Dim lastRow2 As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim recRow As Long
    Dim p As Long
    Dim fCell As Range

    Set wkb1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\James.R.Dickerson\...\09-24-2018-2.xlsx.xlsm")
    Set wks1 = wkb1.Worksheets("Job List")
    Set wkb2 = ThisWorkbook
    Set wks2 = wkb2.Worksheets("Code 200 TECH ASSISTs")

    lRow = 200
    recRow = 1

    For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(iCntr, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(156, 0, 6) Then
            Rows(iCntr).Delete
        End If
    Next

    With wks1
        Set r1 = .Range("C2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns("C:C").Column).End(xlUp))
    End With

    With wks2
        Set r2 = .Range("C2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns("C:C").Column).End(xlUp))
    End With

    lastRow1 = wks2.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    lastRow2 = wks1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For i = 1 To lastRow1
        For j = 1 To lastRow2
            If r2(i).Value <> "" Then 'This will omit blank cells at the end (in the event that the column lengths are not equal.
                If r1(j).Value = r2(i).Value Then
                    r2(i).EntireRow.Delete
                    r1(j).EntireRow.Copy
                    r2(i).EntireRow.Insert
                    r2(i).EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'White background
                    r2(i).EntireRow.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) 'Black font color
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    Exit For
                Else
                    If InStr(1, r1(j).Value, r2(i).Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                        'You may notice in the above instr statement, I have used vbTextCompare instead of its numerical value, _
                        I find this much more reliable.
                        r2(i).EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'White background
                        r2(i).EntireRow.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) 'Black font color
                        Exit For
                    Else
                        r2(i).EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(156, 0, 6) 'Dark red background
                        r2(i).EntireRow.Font.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206) 'Light red font color
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    With wks1
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lastRow
            'See if item is in Master sheet
            Set fCell = wks2.Range("C:C").Find(what:=.Cells(i, "C").Value, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

            If Not fCell Is Nothing Then
                'Record is already in master sheet
                recRow = fCell.Row
            Else
                'Need to move this to master sheet after last found record
                .Cells(i, "C").EntireRow.Copy
                wks2.Cells(recRow + 1, "C").EntireRow.Insert
                wks2.Cells(recRow + 1, "C").EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 190, 8)
                recRow = recRow + 1
            End If
       Next i
    End With


    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    wkb1.Close
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    'ActiveWorkbook.Save
    End Sub
```

Update is the code above works fine, it just skips a few rows and I can not figure out why.  Any assistance is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: In what way does it mess everything up? How does your actual output differ from your expected result?

Comment: So instead of just updating the row, it highlights everything green.  If I comment out the highlight green line in the bottom portion of the code, it doesn't hightight at all and the information doesn't go to the right row

Comment: `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` is handy _once your code works properly_. In the meantime, comment it out - it will make it easier to see what's going on. `On Error Resume Next` is a great way to pretend that there are no bugs in your code and a _fantastic_ way to frustrate yourself. There are _very_ few occasions where it's useful to cover a couple of lines of code, but this isn't one of those situations - remove it. Now see if you're getting any errors that might give you a clue as to what's going wrong with your code.

Comment: I did take out the On Error Resume Next and commented out the screenUpdating parts. I don't get any error from this.

Answer (score 0):

This block:

```
.Cells(p, "C").EntireRow.Copy
wks2.Cells(p, "C").EntireRow.Delete
wks2.Cells(recRow1 + 1, "C").EntireRow.Insert
```

is in wrong order because `.Delete` empties copy buffer so you insert an empty row. Change order of commands this way:

```
wks2.Cells(p, "C").EntireRow.Delete
.Cells(p, "C").EntireRow.Copy
wks2.Cells(recRow1 + 1, "C").EntireRow.Insert
```

and it will be better :)

Comment: I changed what you suggested, now it copies the rows that match up until one that does not match. it stops and gives an error saying object or with variable not set.  It also does not highlight the information that is incoming (new-green) or out going (old-red)

Comment: I have, it gets stuck within the last with loop and highlights everything green.  or when the rows are in different order, they become a mixture of red and greens.